# Pass references to a python function

Tags: python

In this example (which does not work)

```
def foo(x,y):
   x = 42
   y = y * 2

x = 0
y = 2
foo(x,y)
```

I would like `x = 42` and `y = 4`.

The idea behind is to have a wrapper to C functions using ctypes:

```
def foo(self, x, y):
    error = self.dll.foo(self.handler, x, pointer(y))
    if error: 
       self.exception(error)
```

How can I pass parameters as references in Python?

Comment: You cannot pass primitive values by reference, unless you wrap or _box_ the variables into non-primitive objects (i.e., classes or lists) which are always passed by references.

Comment: at least get the example right...

Comment: you have a typo in foo `x = y * 2` should be `y *= 2`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference u will get detail from here about pass by reference in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @musically_ut, you cannot pass primitive values by reference, but you can get newest values by returning from function. Like this:

```
def foo(x,y):
   x = 42
   y = y * 2
   return x,y

x = 0
y = 2
x,y=foo(x,y)
```